# In C#, How to declare DWORD as an uint32?

Tags: c#

I guess the question is really about how to define a type as an existing primitive data type. Below clearly doesn't work, but I think you'll get the idea.

```
Type DWORD = typeof(UInt32);

private DWORD func1(int x)
{
    return 123;
}
```

Comment: Hehehe. No kidding. A friend asked and I couldn't remember the answer. P/Invoked stuff is prolly easier to work with and corresponding docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `typedef` in C#. You can't use `#define` macros to replace strings either (they are just conditional). The only rough equivalent is `using DWORD = System.UInt32;` on top of your source file.

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
using DWORD = System.UInt32;
```

Downside to this is that you'll have to do it in each file that you require it in.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about type aliasing, the way to do that in C# is using the `using` keyword.

e.g.

```
using DWORD = System.Uint32
```